# AngularJS - service variable changes in ng-include view controller not propagating to parent controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an object defined in a service. I am setting the value of the object members from a kendo-ui treeview's select event handler inside of a controller.

I am including this view with the treeview in a second view with a second controller via ng-include. I am attempting to display the service object's values in this "parent" view. I can see that the ng-include controller is setting the value properly for the object in the service. However, the new value is not displaying immediately in the parent view's bindings. It is changing once I navigate to a new view and back, but it is not changing instantly as I expected.

**Service**

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.factory('myService', ['$http','$cacheFactory', '$q','$resource', '$rootScope', myService]);

function myService($http, $cacheFactory, $q, $resource, $rootScope) {

var item = { id: -1 , name: null};

var service = {
    item: item,
    setItem: setItem
};

return service;

function setItem(id) {
    item.id = id;
}
```

**Controller 1**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('controller1',
    ['$scope', 'myService', controller1]);

function controller1($scope, myService) {

    function setItem(e, id) {
        if (id) {
            myService.setItem(id);
        }
    }

    $scope.tvItems = {
        dataSource: ds,
        select: function (e) {
            var id = e.sender.dataItem(e.node).id;
            setItem(e, id);
        }
    };
}
})();
```

**View 1**

```
<div data-ng-controller="controller1">
    <div kendo-tree-view k-options="tvItems"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller 2**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var module = angular.module('newModule', []);

module.controller('controller2', ['$scope','myService', controller2]);

function controller2($scope, myService) {

    $scope.activeItem = myService.item;

    // tried with and without this watch
    $scope.$watch(function () { return myService.item; }, function (item) {
        $scope.activeItem - item;
    }, true);
}
})();
```

**View 2**

```
<div data-ng-include="'view1.html'"></div>
<section data-ng-controller="controller2">
    {{activeItem.id}}
</section>
```

View1 is in the ng-include above. activeItem.id will change but will not render real time, only when navigating to a different view and then back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved by adding $scope.$apply() after myService.setItem(id) in controller 1....not sure that is the proper resolution, but seems to be having the desired effect.